# Mail Probability

Tags: probability

The probability that Marty will receive mail on a given day is 1/3.  What are the probabilities that:

a. Marty receives mail for the first time in the week on Thursday $$= (2/3)^3(1/3)=8/81$$

b. no mail is received during the week (assume a 6 day week); $$= (2/3)^6=64/729$$

c. no mail is received on or after Wednesday of this week? 
originally i thought$$= (2/3)^4=16/81$$

but now I have been told this is wrong, but I don't really understand why. The probability no mail is received on:
Wednesday = 2/3
Thursday =2/3
Friday = 2/3
Saturday = 2/3
So i thought the answer will be $$(2/3)^4$$
Am I thinking about these problems in the right way?

Comment: Under the assumption of independence (not necessarily reasonable, but you are undoubtedly expected to make it) your answers are right.

Comment: @AndréNicolas , Do you think the $(c)$ part is correct? The answer is also same if it means the person doesn't receive a mail until Thursday, but receives on Friday (the 5th day)

Comment: @Tharindu so my answer is wrong?

Comment: I want to make a correction I meant "but he may receive it on Friday (the fifth day).....I think you are correct @MathMajor , but I have a doubt (my mind says might not be right), that is why I asked Andre for an explanation to my thought.

Comment: @Tharindu ok! what did you think of the answer submitted below?

Comment: @MathMajor No offense to anyone, I think the answer your talking about deserves a downvote. It makes no sense to me as to what he's trying to do.

Comment: @Tharindu ok good! Glad I am not the only one who was confused by it

Comment: if the week starts from sunday answers might change , just check according with that ,

Comment: @avz2611 yea I wasn't really sure about that part, but since it was a 6 day week I just assumed Sunday wouldn't count

Comment: I understood why my thought and Andre isn't supporting each other's. It is because It seems to me that Andre has taken the starting day of the week as Sunday (means there is no Saturday) , whereas I have taken it as Monday (in my week there is no Sunday).

Comment: @MathMajor do you know what the answers are

Comment: @avz2611 no, the answers aren't given for this problem unfortunately

Comment: @Tharindu oh I see, yes I am not sure which is the correct way of thinking for this problem since it doesn't specify

Comment: i dont knw whether my logic is right or wrong , but if only one specific mail is in consideration then the answers will be completely different , that is if a mail came on monday it cannot come again as only 1 mail is 2 be delivered . i know this is not a right way to think , but just throwing some ideas. and btw don't worry i don't think your logic is wrong ,

Comment: @avz2611 yea I also thought about that possibility! This is a very unclear question in my opinion

Comment: hey guys, I don't know if you care or not but in a follow up problem it referred to Wednesday as the third day in the week, so I guess we're supposed to take Monday as day 1 and Sunday not existing in this week!

Answer (score -2):

Your answer to the part C is wrong because suppose the mail receive on Monday the probability is $(1/3)*(2/3)^5$ and similarly it can also receive mail on Tuesday we have the sane probability so the answer is sum of these two which is equal to $(2/3)^ 6$. (Assuming 6 days in a week.)

Comment: I'm still not totally understanding

Comment: What are you trying to show? Read the part $c$ Carefully.